# Custom, consecutively numbered group

Tags: numbering, grouping

I'm sure I'm not the first own to ask this question. Sadly, I wasn't able to find an answer just using the search function (probabely I'm using the wrong vocabulary).

The story:
I want to write a report. This report will be grouped into three parts. The report will comprise eleven project descriptions.

Since I use the `\section` command for groups, an example of the structure of this report would be:

```
\section{Intro}
project 1
project 2


\section{Main}
project 3
...
project 10

\section{Conclusion}
project 11
```

**My challenge:**
I would like to use a command called `\project` which looks and works like the `\subsection` command but numbering each project consecutively, i.e. without taking into account the section it is in.

I image something like this:

```
\section{Intro}
\project{How to put an egg into hot water}
\project{How to set a timer}


\section{Main}
\project{How to take an egg out of boiling water}
...
\project{How to open a boiled egg}

\section{Conclusion}
\project{How to eat a boiled egg}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class do you use (or intend to use)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can also be done loading the `chngcntr` package and simply issuing

```
\counterwithout{subsection}{section}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithout{subsection}{section}
\let\project\subsection

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Intro}
\project{How to put an egg into hot water}
\project{How to set a timer}


\section{Main}
\project{How to take an egg out of boiling water}
...
\project{How to open a boiled egg}

\section{Conclusion}
\project{How to eat a boiled egg}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

I would also suggest to format the "projects" so to have the word "Project" behind them.

This can be done with the help of the `titlesec` and `titletoc` packages and through these definitions:

```
\titlecontents{subsection}[3.8em]
{\hspace*{-2.3em}Project\ }
{\hspace*{2.3em}\contentslabel{2.3em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[.75pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{Project\ \thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\titlecontents{subsection}[3.8em]
{\hspace*{-2.3em}Project\ }
{\hspace*{2.3em}\contentslabel{2.3em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[.75pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{Project\ \thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\counterwithout{subsection}{section}
\let\project\subsection

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Intro}
\project{How to put an egg into hot water}
\project{How to set a timer}


\section{Main}
\project{How to take an egg out of boiling water}
...
\project{How to open a boiled egg}

\section{Conclusion}
\project{How to eat a boiled egg}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Package `remreset` allows the removal of a counter from the reset list of the parent counter. `\thesubsection` can then be redefined to exclude the section number. Then `\project` is just `\subsection`.

The example also redefines `\thesection` to have a different numbering scheme for sections.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\let\project\subsection
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Intro}
\project{How to put an egg into hot water}
\project{How to set a timer}


\section{Main}
\project{How to take an egg out of boiling water}
...
\project{How to open a boiled egg}

\section{Conclusion}
\project{How to eat a boiled egg}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: `chngcntr` is much easier than `remreset`